# App built with Android Studio Arctic Fox doesn't run on Android devices

Tags: android-studio

I lately upgrade Android studio from 4.2.x to Arctic Fox (on Ubuntu 20.04), did the required reconfiguration (mainly changing from JDK 8 to JDK 11), then rebuilt and installed the app (debug version) on Android devices (with Android 9 and Android 6).  Everything seems to work without error, except that the debugger doesn't launch the app and I have to launch the app manually.  But after I tap on the icon,
the app doesn't run on the devices, which only say "App isn't installed".  I googled in the whole afternoon and got no references on that.  What can be wrong?  Am I the only one getting this problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the problem.

It turns out as Arctic Fox requires explicitly setting android:exported for all activities in AndroidManifest.xml.  I set android:exported="false" to my default activity.  Change it to "true" solved the problem.